# How to create a user defined function in sqlite or get distance between 2 geopints?

Tags: android, sqlite, geolocation, distance

I want to calculate distance between two geopoints one point which is stored in my local db and other point is my current location.How can I get it.

I want to fire

```
SELECT *, 3956 * 2 * ASIN ( SQRT ( POWER ( SIN((@orig_lat - abs(dest.lat)) * pi()/180   / 2), 2) +  COS(@orig_lat * pi()/180 )
* COS(abs(dest.lat) * pi()/180) *  POWER(SIN((@orig_lon – dest.lon) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) 
)) as  distance FROM hotels dest having distance < @dist ORDER BY distance limit 10;
```

this query in sqlite,but as I read on sqlite and stackoveflow that Sqlite doesn't support math functions.

So anyone know how  to create user define function for this query in sqlite using `C library` and `android NDK`? or have another way to find it out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [SpatiaLite functions](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-4.0.0.html) are overkill, but certainly do what you need.

> SpatiaLite is an open source library intended to extend the SQLite core to support fully fledged Spatial SQL capabilities.

There is an [Android version](https://code.google.com/p/spatialite-android/).